# Expression for hyperbola on complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis, conic-sections, conformal-geometry

The hyperbola

$$x^2 - y^2 = 1$$

has a simple expression in the complex plane as $\{z^2 + \bar{z}^2 = 2\}$.

Is there a similarly simple expression for a hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$? Or an ellipse?

I know we can express hyperbolae and ellipses as images of vertical and horizontal lines under the sine function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there's one way to find out.  Solving the system
$$z = x + iy$$
$$\overline{z} = x - i y$$
for $x$ and $y$, we get
$$x = \frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$$
and
$$y = \frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}.$$
Plugging these into the equation 
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1,$$
we get
$$\frac{(z+\overline{z})^2}{4a^2} + \frac{(z-\overline{z})^2}{4b^2}=1.$$
If there's no relation between $a$ and $b$ then the $z \overline{z}$ term won't cancel like it did in the $a = b$ case you gave above.

However, if instead of starting with an equation like $x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1$ you think more geometrically there's a better way of doing things.  If we let $p$ and $q$ be the foci of a hyperbola, we can write an equation like
$$||z - p| - |z - q|| = 2a$$
which simply encodes the geometric definition of the hyperbola.

Comment: +1. Is there any condition which is nessesary for $p,q$ and for $a$. Or, they can be any arbitrary constants?

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are the foci, so they can be arbitrary.  We do need $a > 0$ to rule out a degenerate case.